# Python - Can't install pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using Windows 10.

In my project folder, I'm trying to test it as an exe.

So, I did this to install Pyinstaller:
`py -m pip install pyinstaller`

And it said it installed.
But when I did `py -m pyinstaller emu.py`, it just returned this:

`C:\Users\tux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller`

Can someone help?
If I try to install pyinstaller using PIP again, it comes up with this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4 in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2022.8)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2022.5.30 in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2022.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (58.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\tux\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2022.5.30->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
```

It's saying Pyinstaller is already installed, but python doesn't recognise it.

Before you ask, if I try to just run pyinstaller as a standalone command, it says it cannot find pyinstaller.

Edit: It's been over a month and nobody has replied.
Forget it. I'm just not gonna make the application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the generic way

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

also refer to this pypi link https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/